# customizing the app bar in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I noticed that internet explorer has an app bar that is non standard. It has the standard ... Button that expands the app bar to show additional options but rather than app bar buttons it has the address ba and a refresh button. 
does anyone know how one would go about overriding the app bar in a similar way, i cant find a way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't** extend the application bar beyond what's already offered in the SDK. You'll need to implement your own XAML version of the application bar since you can't tweak the shell object to contain additional visual components.

Comment: Shame. Surprising that nobody has written a custom control for this. I take it that the app bar can't be subclassed to achieve this?